# How to handling incoming sms when app is active

Tags: ios, xcode, sms, ios5.1

I'm developing an iOS app that sends sms. What's the best way to handle a incoming message when the app is active. Is this done automatically or do I have to code for this in my app via the

```
applicationWillResignActive:(UIApplication *)application
```

method?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by handling the SMS?

Comment: my app is active and the user receives a incoming text.will ios handle this automatically or do i have to code within the app to handle this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to/shouldn't need to deal with incoming SMSs.

When the device receives an SMS (or an iMessage these days), then the user will be notified by their method of choice. They may leave your application via that notification, but you cannot determine that it was the SMS that caused it.

CoreTelephony provides some abilities for people to deal with Calls, but nothing to do with SMS. Sorry. As such your app cannot determine the state of SMS messages. You're able to send SMS messages because the OS provides you with a view controller to do so, but you can't do anything else with them.

Comment: so ios will provide a alert with the message content and allow for the user to bring my app back to active state.Am i correct in this assumption?

Comment: found a great link for this info. http://books.google.ca/books?id=C3aovKAzSOQC&pg=PA281&lpg=PA281&dq=applicationWillResignActive+sms&source=bl&ots=MByL2P0ByC&sig=EG4YI1P4y9Mp9Yb2t5bQIYxU5n0&hl=en&sa=X&ei=17CGUMWnMsjt0gGbuYGwDQ&ved=0CE4Q6AEwBzgK#v=onepage&q=applicationWillResignActive%20sms&f=false

Comment: @user1725650 You don't need to do a single thing, the OS will take care of it for you. The user will know how to get back to your application if they leave for a minute to read their messages.

Comment: Thank You all.That's why I come here.Great people with great answers.